# JavaScript Custom Form Validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am new to JavaScript and tend to get stuck with some problems. I was trying to create a custom validation for a form, which consists from 4 inputs, but the code doesn't work for me. Does anyone have any ideas how can I fix it? Here is just one of the inputs:

```
          <div class="inputWrapper">
            <input class="formInput required type="text" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="Email Address"/>
            <img class="errorImg hidden" src="/images/icon-error.svg" />
            <div id="emailError" class="errorMessage hidden">
              <i>Email cannot be empty</i>
            </div>
          </div>
```

I also have two divs that should appear, when the input is submitted with error, before that they have a class "hidden" with display none.

```
"use strict";

const formInput = document.querySelector(`.formInput`);
const errorImg = document.querySelector(`.errorImg`);
const errorMessage = document.querySelector(`.errorMessage`);

const input = formInput.nodeValue;

const errorOccured = function () {
  errorMessage.classList.remove(`hidden`);
  errorImg.classList.remove(`hidden`);
};

form.addEventListener("submit", function () {
  if (input === ``) {
    errorOccured();
  }
});
```

This is how the page looks like itself:
[image]

Comment: Pass in the `EventObject` and `EventObject.preventDefault()` in your `submit` Listener. And I wouldn't use Template Literals unless you need something to be parsed, as it just takes longer to process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read input value in the event listener function

```
let form = document.querySelector("#form1");
form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    const input = formInput.value;
    if (input === '') {
        errorOccured();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```